# Summary of categorical variables pandas

Tags: python, pandas

As stated in the title, I want to conduct some summary analysis about categorical variables in `pandas`, but have not come across a satisfying solution after searching for a while. So I developed the following code as kind of a self answering-question with the hope that someone out there on SO can help to improve.

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['a', 'b','b','c'],
                        'y':[1, 0, 0, np.nan],
                        'z':['Jay', 'Jade', 'Jia', ''],
                        'u':[1, 2, 3, 3]})
def cat_var_describe(input_df, var_list):
    df = input_df.copy()
    # dataframe to store result
    res = pd.DataFrame({'var_name', 'values', 'count'})
    for var in var_list:
        temp_res = df[var].value_counts(dropna=False).rename_axis('unique_values').reset_index(name='counts')
        temp_res['var_name'] = var
        if var==var_list[0]:
            res = temp_res.copy()
        else:
            res = pd.concat([res, temp_res], axis=0)
    res = res[['var_name', 'unique_values', 'counts']]
    return res

cat_des_test = cat_var_describe(test_df, ['x','y','z','u'])
cat_des_test
```

Any helpful suggestions will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the pandas DataFrame `describe()` method.
`describe()` includes only numerical data by default.
to include categorical variables you must use the `include` argument.

using `'object'` returns only the non-numerical data

```
 test_df.describe(include='object')
```

using `'all'` returns a summary of all columns with `NaN` where the statistic is inappropriate for the datatype

```
 test_df.describe(include='all')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `unique()` method to get a list of individual values for a column, for example:

```
test_df['x'].unique()
```

For getting the number of occurrences of values in a column, you can use `value_counts()`:

```
test_df['x'].value_counts()
```

A simplified loop over all columns of the `DataFrame` could look like this:

```
for col in list(test_df):
  print('variable:', col)
  print(test_df[col].value_counts(dropna=False).to_string())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use describe Function

```
test_df.describe()
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html